# How to perform right outer join using aggregation lookup on mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

First of all I know I can achieve the result I'm expecting by changing the lookup collection to another one but in my case I cant do that.

I have collections name `col1` and `col2` with following data

`col1` :

```
{
  "id" : "1"
  "name" : "sam"
  "age" : 20
}
```

`col2` :

```
{
  "id" : "1"
  "name" : "ryan"
  "age" : 10
}
{
  "id" : "2"
  "name" : "tyler"
  "age" : 20
}
```

I want to find documents from ***col2*** where age not equal to 20 using aggregation(**this is a simplified example**)

I can write query using lookup to get common results from both collections but how can I get the right outer join documents from `col2`

I am executing this aggregation on `col2` with lookup `path:'col1'`

Expected result after aggregation :

```
{
  "id" : "1"
  "name" : "ryan"
  "age" : 10
}
```

Comment: can you add your expected result as per your documents.

Comment: @turivishal added expected result

Comment: you need to filter age condition from both collection and return common document?

Comment: @turivishal I want to filter using common age and return uncommon document